# Raspberry Wifi configuration

Tags: linux, wifi, raspbian

English is not my mother language, but I hope you can understand me. I have bought a Raspberry Pi 2. I installed Raspbian and I bought a Wifi too. This one:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/271857752471?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT
I'm new too use Raspberry and I've never use Raspbian and other 'Linux' distribution... So, my biggest problem is, that raspberry doesn't recognize my wifi. I've tried to download this package: http://driver.iigoal.com/drivers/SKU108764.rar 
I've tried to do what is in the guide, but I can't... Perhaps can somebody write down a description (or a short video:)), how I need to do these things?

Answer (score 0):

The WiFi adapter listing on eBay does not list Linux as a compatible OS, but it lists the driver as being Realtek RTL8192cu.

I researched a little about that driver in regards to raspbian and it should have two potential drivers. the first is built into the kernel/base installation. It's module is named 8192cu.ko.

A second option exists, though it appears to be a bit experimental that comes from an RTLwifi set.

Since this is a fresh installation, I would recommend starting fresh and ensuring that the WiFi dongle is plugged in during the Raspbian installation/first boot. This should ensure that it is identified and loaded properly.

If that does not work, I would recommend plugging in the rPi 2 with an ethernet cable and running updates to the system, that may help download anything it identifies as missing or old and other greater compatibility

Comment: Hi, I've updated Raspbian, but it doesn't help. I think the wifi dongle doesn't work, because I've tried to use on my Windows laptop too... :(

Comment: That is unfortunate that you got a lemon, but it is completely possible. The drivers are built into the Raspbian installation so if it were working it would not have required any special configuration on your part. Is Windows even seeing the wireless adapter in the device manager?

Answer (score 0):

Plug-in the wifi adapter to a usb port,open up a terminal on Raspberry pi and type

```
lsusb
```

it will display all the usb devices in the system.
if there is an entry for your wifi adapter then it is easy to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

my raspberry pi work with hardware what you bought in eBay, without more configuration as: wifi-data in wpa-supplicant, if you use terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and write

```
network={
        ssid="NETWORK_NAME"
        psk="NETWORK_PASSWORD"
}
```

this is normal rule for wifi configuration in raspberry pi